# How to tell if the iphone 5 is connected to the 2.4 or 5 ghz network?

Tags: macos, wifi, iphone

I just got a new 5th generation apple airport extreme and I set it up in the dual band mode and I am wondering if it is possible to see which frequency the iphone 5 is connecting to. I know that on the computer you can hold down option when clicking on the wifi menu, but I would really like to know which one my iphone is connecting to.

Comment: Is there no possible way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

See the answers to this [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73719/how-can-i-tell-which-band-2-4ghz-or-5ghz-my-iphones-wifi-connection-is-on).

Since you are using an AirPort Extreme, you can set up a separate SSID for the 5GhZ-network and connect to that one manually on your phone, and from there be able to see which network you're on. To do this, follow the below step:

> Airport Utility 6.0: Airport Extreme > Edit > Wireless > Wireless Options > Tick the box next to "5GHz network name".
>   Airport Utility 5.6 and earlier: Manual Setup > Wireless > Wireless Network Options > Tick the box.
>   <sup>[Source](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=14532247&postcount=11)</sup>

P.S. Having a different SSID does not make it a separate network, it just makes the two bands differentiable.